# Positive real solutions to $a + b = c + d$ with $ab<cd$, $a<c$ and $d<b$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I would appreciate your help with this problem:

Given that $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are positive real numbers satisfying
$$ab < cd$$
$$a < c$$
$$d < b,$$
is it possible that  $a + b = c + d$ ?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Take $a=1$, $b=3$, $c=2$, $d=2$, for example.